# Is it possible to assign borders to an html table dynamically using CSS and the td value of the cell only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sql

I have data coming in from a database that is loaded into an html table.  Because of this, I can't easily add different classes and id's to td's.

So I have a table of values in a table, call it table 1.  Then I have another set of values in a separate query that have the values of each "group".  This is loaded into an html variable which is loaded into a non-displaying table, call this table 2. The group values in table 2 are what I want to use to assign the new borders in table 1 with.  The values in table 1 don't matter.

So essentially, I want to use table 2 values to assign the borders on table 1.  The values in table 2 are like this (I'd prefer not to change these if possible):

```
0   1.1   1.2   1.3   2.1   2.2   2.3   3.1
```

I would assign each group number (1.1 for example) with a certain border style which would apply to the other table.

I'm not too savvy with all of this stuff yet so often times I don't know if what I want to do is possible or not.  So please let me know if you have any ideas or if you think it's just not going to happen.

I'm able to incorporate javascript, jquery, sql, css and html elements, but this runs on a local machine so no php, etc. The data comes from a database so if there is a trick to applying something through sql keep that idea in mind.

Here is an old fiddle showing the "table 1" loaded using html table strings as variables (instead of originating from sql). This is not how it currently works, but it shows what it looks like.

[Sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56B5p/2/)  Slide the sliders and the data will appear.

The table 1 has a bunch of values in it.  I will load another table, table 2, that will have the group values in it and I want to apply this to the table 1.

Thanks for the assist!

Comment: Some kind of fiddle or demo with dummy data in a table layout would be helpful.

Comment: I would if I could, but the way it's set up it only works on a local machine with some tricky workarounds. It doesn't run off a sql server, it runs off of an access DB local js access script.

Comment: If you can assign id's and td's you can probably use that 'html variable' and instead of creating a non-displaying table use js/jquery to iterate through this variable and create your css needed for table 1.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can since the data originates from a sql query and is parsed into html. The table with the data in table 1 doesn't contain the data in table 2 which has the groups in it. Unless someone knows how to do some sql trickery.

Comment: Why don't you create a new table with the styling rules that you want, and populate it using the table data being loaded via javascript?

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you explained how the group values in table 2 relate to the values in table 1.

Comment: @wahwahwah, are you suggesting that I pull the data in from both tables and combine them together using jquery and then use standard ids and classes to make the table formatting?

Comment: There's several ways you can accomplish what - I think - you are trying to do. You say "I would assign each group number a border style which would apply to the other table"... How? How are the values in Table 1 related to the "Group Numbers" in Table 2?

Comment: The output is kind of like a "Cell map".  The table 1 shows a shape of some sort that each part of the shape is assigned a group.  See the fiddle example in the question above. Each <td> would be assigned a "group number" so that every <td> would have a number assigned. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

since html doesn't use variables, I believe you mean javascript variables. 
let us call the variable you will store your "group" in group.

```
 var group = document.getElementById('table2').value
```

if you want to base your border color for table1 on the value stored in a field of table2, try something like the following switch(case) statement. Obviously, you will substitute the actual div id you are referencing in table2 and the actual div id you assign to your table1. This is just an overview you can use as a template. For instance, if you want to change the border width, instead of color, your code blocks would be document.getElementById('table1').style.borderWidth = "thick"; etc.

```
  switch(group){
    case 0:
    document.getElementById('table1').style.borderColor = "red";
    break;
    case 1.1:
    document.getElementById('table1').style.borderColor = "blue";
    break;
    case 1.2:
    document.getElementById('table1').style.borderColor = "yellow";
    default:
    document.getElementById('table1').style.borderColor = "black";
```

}

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that html has no variables.  The html tables are stored as variables in the JavaScript but this is not how I do it in the new version.